# UNREGISTERED ON GOOGLE DEVELOPER CONSOLE error

Tags: android-studio, google-authentication, google-developers-console

I had a running app which I migrated from eclipse to Android Studio. I had a google sign in feature which was functional, but it is breaking after importing to AS with the above mentioned error. I receive this as the time of fetching token during authentication form google. I understand that there would be a change in debug signature from eclipse to Android Studio. But as I see, there is no place to mention the signature of the application in google developer console ( I am using an unrestricted key for now). I have also checked the api key which is matching between server and my app. I get the error a this line of code :

```
GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, mEmail, mScope);
```

How can i go about investigating this issue?